# Can a Wakelock be released automatically?

Tags: android

I inicialize a wakelock in the onStartCommand of a service:

```
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
wl.acquire();
```

I want the wakelock active because I need to recognize a shake event at any time, even with the screen locked.

When the service is up for a long time and I destroy it, it gives an error when acessing the wakelock on the destroy method:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorListener);
    if(wl.isHeld())
        wl.release();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Is the wakelock released at some point automatically?

Is there a more correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error do you get?

Assuming your Service isn't strictly "one-shot" you should be getting several calls to onStartCommand on the same service instance - thus creating a lot of wakelocks. Don't do that.

Start by moving the creation of the `WakeLock` to your `Service#onCreate()` - you only really ever need one. If you want to keep the device awake until you kill your service "manually" I'd recommend that you `WakeLock#aquire()` in `Service#onCreate()`, no point in calling it more than once.

If you insist on keeping the `WakeLock#aquire()` in `Service#onStartCommand()` you need to keep track of the number of times you've called it (since it is reference counted by default) - or turn of reference counting on the `WakeLock` when you create it by calling `WakeLock#setReferenceCounted(false)`.

Comment: I've changed to the Service#onCreate(). If it gives error again I'll tell you what it is later on.